# What does the STATUS_NOT_ACTIVE status in newsletter mean?

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, newsletter

In the Magento2 newsletter, there are 4 statuses. Here's my interpretation of them:

1. `STATUS_SUBSCRIBED` - User has confirmed and subscribed to newsletter
2. `STATUS_NOT_ACTIVE` - ???
3. `STATUS_UNSUBSCRIBED` - User *may or may
       not* have confirmed his email address but is certainly not subscribed
       to newsletter
4. `STATUS_UNCONFIRMED` - User has subscribed to newsletter but has not
   confirmed his email address

Is my understanding of the statuses correct? And what does `STATUS_NOT_ACTIVE` mean?

Answer (score 4):

I think your interpretation is correct for STATUS_SUBSCRIBED and STATUS_UNSUBSCRIBED, but there is a subtlety you've missed for STATUS_UNCONFIRMED.

The difference between STATUS_UNCONFIRMED and STATUS_NOT_ACTIVE hinges on whether the newsletter subscription was created as part of a customer account or was created as a stand alone newsletter sign up.

- STATUS_SUBSCRIBED - active newsletter subscriptions
- STATUS_NOT_ACTIVE - waiting for user to click activation link in the *newsletter subscription* confirmation email
- STATUS_UNSUBSCRIBED - user or admin has unsubscribed the user from the newsletter
- STATUS_UNCONFIRMED - waiting for the user to click the activation link the *customer account confirmation* email

If a visitor just subscribes to the site's newsletter, without creating an customer account at the same time, then depending on the config value of newsletter/subscription/confirm (set in Stores>>Configuration>>Customers>>Newsletter>>Subscription Options>>Need to Confirm), the associated subscription will either get the status STATUS_SUBSCRIBED or STATUS_NOT_ACTIVE.

If a visitor signs up for a new account and checks the box to subscribe to the newsletter at the same time, then depending on the config value of customer/create_account/confirm (set in Stores>>Configuration>>Customers>>Customer Configuration>>Create New Account Options>>Require Emails Confirmation), the associated newsletter subscription will either get the status STATUS_SUBSCRIBED or STATUS_UNCONFIRMED.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, `STATUS_NOT_ACTIVE` is used for Newsletter confirmation:
Enable Newsletter confirmation: **STORE > Configuration > CUSTOMERS > Newsletter > Need to confirm > Yes**. The customer subscribes a different email.

If user subscribes own login email, confirmation doesn't needed.

Take a look: `vendor/magento/module-newsletter/Model/Subscriber.php::subsc‌​ribe($email)` to see more details.

Comment: Under what condition will `STATUS_NOT_ACTIVE` be set to a subscriber's status?

Comment: Take a look: `vendor/magento/module-newsletter/Model/Subscriber.php::subscribe($email)` to see more details.

Comment: The logged customer subscribes a different email.

Comment: Not really, I have tried changing email address as a logged in customer and my status remains as STATUS_SUBSCRIBED. The only time I get STATUS_NOT_ACTIVE is when I subscribe as a guest user. Is this correct?

Comment: Thanks, I not check with a guest user. In case- logged, should try: Logged > Subscribe a different email.